# Gmail API reading email

Tags: python, google-apps-script, gmail

I can't seem to understand why I keep getting this type of error:

> An error occurred: 'parts'

Can it be because of different languages from English or is it an Image?

I tried rewriting the code, receiving labels from mail list does work I just can't seem to open the messages.

```py
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']
    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])

        if not messages:
            print('No messages found.')
            return

        else:
            message_count = 0
            for message in messages:
                msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id'], format='full').execute()
                email_data = msg['payload']['headers']
                for values in email_data:
                    name = values['name']
                    if name == 'From':
                        from_name = values['value']

                        for part in msg['payload']['parts']:
                            try:
                                data = part['body']["data"]
                                byte_code = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
                                text = byte_code.decode("utf-8")

                                print(f'This is the message:{from_name} - {str(text)}')

                            except BaseException as error:
                                pass
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

Comment: Because you have all-catching `except Exception as error`... Remove that try/except and get full traceback

Comment: You have `KeyError('parts')` in `msg['payload']['parts']`.

Comment: Also there is no point of catching HttpError, because it will be caught by `except Exception as error` anyways

Comment: I am a beginner if anyone can help me see the problem in the code except removing the `try: except:` which i did and as you guys said`KeyError` in `'parts'`